# how the server get user information when git clone through ssh without adding ssh key

Tags: git

I remove ssh key from github account abd when executing the command as below:

```
git clone git@xxx.git
```

it prompt passsword input and I give password but it gives me:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I ensure the password is valid for I can use it to login my github. My confusion is that how the server know who am I or how *git clone* command tell the Identity of me to the server ? I doubt that maybe server dont know who am I so that password cant match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how the server know who am I or how git clone command tell the Identity of me

Depends on the protocol. For `https://` you pass your login/password directly:

```
git clone https://user:passwd@example.com/repo.git
```

If you don't provide the password:

```
git clone https://user@example.com/repo.git
```

`git` asks for it.

But with `ssh` protocol

```
git clone ssh://git@example.com/repo.git
```

or

```
git clone git@example.com:repo.git
```

the login name is `git` so the only way for the server to authenticate you is by an ssh keypair. That is the server must know your public key.

Comment: About ssh protocal.  should I give the password of git user if I dont copy public key in github ssh keys? I give passwd of user when I ssh user@ip. But now It make no difference when I give password of my github account. It seemed I should give password of user git(git@example.com:XX.git).

Comment: And how the server build the dependency between public key and user, otherwise how it judge whether my passwd is valid?

Comment: You cannot give password for user `git` — there is no password. Github and any other git hosting recognize users by their keypairs. So the hosting must have your public key and when you login your `ssh` client sends a (fingerprint of) the public key so the server matches the key from its database.